# An Android Virtual Device that failed to load

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Note: this question is very similar to another question posed much earlier by another person, but does not solve my problem. (*not* the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749711/an-android-virtual-device-that-failed-to-load-click-details-to-see-the-error))

Situation: I just installed Eclipse/ADK/Android SDK, etc. and made sure to download/install Android 2.2, 4.2.2, & 4.4.2 from the SDK Manager.

I am now trying to create an Android Virtual Device akin to the Google Nexus 5, which uses 4.4.2.   **Using 512 MB of RAM**

Problem arises when I finish "creating" it, the AVD fails to load. I can dismiss this error, but I actually can't run anything on that AVD - it's just a black screen... not even the simple Hello World!

[image: AVD crashes when loading.]

When I try to launch an application, I get the following error:

```
Android Launch! adb is running normally. 

Performing com.XXX.myapp001.StartingPoint activity launch

Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554' 

Uploading TheNewBoston.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' Installing TheNewBoston.apk... 

Installation error: Unknown failure 

Please check logcat output for more details. 

Launch canceled!
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are the memory settings at? I once had the same error, I had to reduce the size of the RAM.

Comment: 512mb of ram. (just added above to avoid future confusion)

Comment: I would set that lower, a lot lower just to see if it comes up. I had the exact same problem like a month ago. Can you make other devices or is it just the Nexus 5? If nothing else, set all the settings down until you figure out which one is the culprit. I know it's a pain but the way virtualization works, it's picky with when it feels like being "compatible". HARDWARE ACCELERATION is also one that doesn't play nicely for me.

Comment: I get the same error creating an AVD for other versions: a) Nexus S with 343mb using 4.1.2, b) generic, 256mb 3.7" wvga, etc... I really don't think its the AVD configuration, but rather something with my setup... strange because i followed all the steps and cross-checked with multiple different sources (TheNewBoston, SamsTeachYourself, GoogleDev, etc.)

Comment: Check the SDK manager if you have any updates. What's your operating system, and which IDE are you using? Have you tried starting the AVD without attaching anything to it?

Comment: Yeah - SDK was updated when I installed yesterday. IDE = Eclipse with ADT bundle from Google website. I tried starting it w/o any attachments, just running from the AVD manager...

Comment: My last suggestion is that you might want to try using the INTEL instead of the ARM. Keep swapping settings around and keep your memory settings low, because that should be the longest part (memory allocation).

Comment: well - we are getting somewhere. The emulator actually started for a bit, but then I got "emulator-x86.exe has stopped working". The error message in the dialog just before that window was "emulator: Failed to open HAX device!"

Comment: found solution: was HAX allocation. Solution can be found in the following video >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXnm8Lsl-dg

Comment: Make sure to post your own answer, so functionally, someone can stumble upon it and know right away. Glad you're up and at 'em.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot to re-post this answer that I put in the comments section of my original post chain.

**solution:** was HAX allocation. Solution can be found in the following [video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=tXnm8Lsl-dg).

Answer (score 17):

There is a black screen with nothing loading is because you didn't specify the skin when loading the virtual device. Try selecting "WVGA800"

Comment: Thanks this works but "WVGA800" cuts off part of my screen for Nexus 5