# Failed to load Android emulator in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I am getting this error while creating Android virtual device in Android Studio.
please help me to solve this.
please find the screenshot in this link
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ysZ.png]

Comment: possible duplicate of [An Android Virtual Device that failed to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597781/an-android-virtual-device-that-failed-to-load)

Comment: yes.i deleted avd folder .then i created new emulator.now its working.thank you @RedShift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that chosen Device Android API Version is supposed to be installed in Android Studio, as you can see from AVD Manager. But in SDK Manager it is not installed.

Dowload and install it in SDK Manager first, then create device with this API version.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced a similar problem, I solved it by moving Android Studio to the same directory as sdk. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Recreating** the emulator.
Remove the Current Emulator that fails. then Create it Again.
and... try Genymotion too.