# Android Virtual Device isn't launching because of an error. (Screenshots below)

Tags: android, android-studio

So, I tried to run the AVD for the first time, and it showed the following errors and didn't launch at all. Please help me resolve this issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC8AI.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1lvB.jpg

Comment: In first screenshot, you can see error is mentioned up there as "Failed to Parse properties from C:\Users\*\config.ini" So instead asking a new question you could search that error on Stackoverflow as answer to this question is already provided on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813888/6791222. So this question might be the duplicate.

Comment: You need to install proper selected API version from SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384494/3974530